# MySQL event scheduler waiting on empty queue since server restarted 12 days ago

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-8.0, mysql-event

I noticed a process on the server which has been running for more than 12 days, which I think coincides with the last time MySQL was restarted.

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

+---------+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Id      | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time    | State                  | Info                  |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|       5 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL | Daemon  | 1098372 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL                  |
| 1774483 | root            | localhost | NULL | Query   |       0 | starting               | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+---------+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+---------+------------------------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are no events, and I haven't attempted to created any.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.EVENTS;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

This is actively using up to 8% of my server's CPU.

Is there a way of determining what this is, or why it was started? Will this try to run every time I restart MySQL? If so, what is it 'waiting' for and do I need to tweak my configuration at all to prevent this?

**MySQL 8.0.21**

Comment: Could you post results of HTOP or TOP?

Comment: Could you also post results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%event%; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%event%'; for analysis and confirmation nothing EVENT driven has been used since instance start.

Comment: Did your 8% CPU use go away with event_scheduler = OFF ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Yes, it was only the event scheduler using 8% CPU so once I disabled it the process ended.

Comment: One more way to save CPU cycles.  Thanks, Wilson

Comment: hi how did you know that the event_Scheduler  was using this amount of CPU, please !!

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ I can't remember exactly, but I'm guessing I was looking at `htop` or something on the command line and traced it to the event scheduler process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The event_Scheduler is, as it's name suggests, a way to Schedule Events (in this case queries) to run in MySQL at a given time. It is simply waiting for an event to trigger it and tell it to do something. As you can see you have no events set up, so it will be waiting for a long time.

It is enabled by default, but can be disabled by running:

`SET @@global.event_scheduler = 0;`

You also want to add:

`event_scheduler = OFF`

to your my.cnf file to prevent it starting after a reboot.

Comment: Does disabling of it make any difference in performance while insertion/updation/SELECTion is being done in multiple threads?